# Wordpress Database Error using $wpdb->get_results()

Tags: shortcode, database

I am trying to run a query from my functions.php inside a shortcode

See code

```
function nrl_listing_page($args) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->show_errors( true );
    $properties = $wpdb->wp_nrl_properties;
    $sql = " SELECT * FROM  $roperties" ;
    $query = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A );

    if (is_null($results)) {
    echo "Big Fat Falure!!!!";
} else {
    echo $query;
   echo "Success!!!";
}
}
add_shortcode( 'nrl_listing_creator', 'nrl_listing_page' );
```

I get this error when I try to use the shortcode in a page

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '' at line 1] SELECT * FROM

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: probably `$wpdb->wp_nrl_properties` is not defined and so your query is `SELECT * FROM` which is not valid because no table has been selected.

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: Try `var_dump($roperties);` also try `$sql = " SELECT * FROM" . $roperties;`

Comment: I also noticed typo error instead of `$properties` you have `$roperties"`

Comment: Still no dice, the same error persists

Comment: which table do you want select? by default there is no _wp_nrl_properties_

Comment: It is a custom table that I created in the wordpress database

Comment: `$properties = $wpdb->prefix . 'nrl_properties';` is the typical way you would use custom tables.